# Как устранить ошибку в Android Studio (не удается найти файл cache.properties)?

Tags: android-studio

Ни с того ни с сего, все время неактивна кнопка запуска и debug в Android Studio. на всех продуктах.
После перезапуска компа стала появляться такая ошибка (см картинку). Переустановил студию - не помогло. Как исправить?

Поискал указанный файл, вместо "cache.properties" находится "cache.properties.lock".
Попробовал переименовать в "cache.properties", так при нажатии в студии на "Try Again" - создается рядом с переименованным файлом еще один: "cache.properties.lock"..

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 3):

Нашла ответ в англоязычном варианте.
1. Найти папку .\grable\caches\x.x\
2. Из нее скопировать scripts, scripts-remapped в другую директорию (на всяких случай)
3. Удалить .\grable\caches\x.x\
4. Выполнить синхронизацию проекта.
 Готово.
Мне помогло.

Comment: Если вдруг кому-то пригодится, вот оригинал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего обновление каких то ресурсов произошло с ошибкой. Попробуйте импортировать проект в студию, изначально удалив папку .`idea` и `app.iml` из вашего проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Просто удали его. Android Studio создаст сам свой новый файл.